# algún tiempo vs algo de tiempo

Tags: uso-de-palabras, adjetivos

Is there any difference in meaning between "algo de tiempo" and "algún tiempo" ?

- Necesitamos algo de tiempo.
- Necesitamos algún tiempo.

Is the former more usual?

Comment: Maybe the conceivable interval of time is a bit broader in "necesitamos algún tiempo."  I agree with @Gustavson that the other sentence is more common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say that:

- Necesitamos **algún** tiempo.

is much less usual than:

- Necesitamos **algo de** tiempo.

I think the register is approximately the same.

We can also say:

- Necesitamos **un** tiempo.

or

- Necesitamos **un poco de** tiempo.

both of which are as usual as "Necesitamos algo de tiempo".